# Text field "Element not interactable" no matter what

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to automate screenshots from the VAT check website. Example CSV file with three columns: 1st Client Name, 2nd Country Code and 3rd VAT number. The code is able to choose the country from the dropdown, but not able to enter the VAT number into the text field (Element not interactable) WebDriverWait does not help.

```
import csv
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    data = list(reader)
client_name = data[1][0]
country = data[1][1]
vat_number = data[1][2]

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/#/vat-validation')

dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//select[@id="select-country"]'))
dropdown.select_by_value(country)

driver.implicitly_wait(5) 

vat_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="vat-validation-form"]').send_keys(vat_number)

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_id('submit')
submit_button.click()

now = datetime.datetime.now()
date_string = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
filename = f'{date_string}_{client_name}.png'
driver.save_screenshot(filename)

driver.quit()
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: NOTE: You are using `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` like it actually waits when you call it. It instead is a one-time call to set the wait time. The Selenium lead and devs have stated that implicit waits should not be used. You should instead use `WebDriverWait` as needed.

Comment: @Mixd_Toms, Please check out the updated answer. It is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @KunduK It works, thanks! Maybe you can help with my most recent question? I'm trying to loop this through all the rows in data.csv

Comment: @MIXD_Toms, I have working solution for you. can you open your question again?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75755064/how-to-loop-selenium-code-through-all-csv-rows?noredirect=1#comment133638443_75755064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath provided doesn't identify the INPUT element. It is identifying the FORM element. That's why it throws the `ElementNotInteractableException`.

Try the XPath below which identifies the INPUT element.

```
//input[@formcontrolname="vatNumber"]
```

Ideally it should be

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@formcontrolname="vatNumber"]').send_keys(vat_number)
```

**Update:**

Use WebDriverWait() and wait for element to be clickable.

```
driver.get("https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/#/vat-validation")
dropdown = Select(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//select[@id="select-country"]'))))
dropdown.select_by_value("BE")
vatNumber=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@formcontrolname="vatNumber"]')))
vatNumber.click()
vatNumber.send_keys("VAT0000000000001")
```

you need to import below libraries.

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]